# Copy files above 500kB from one directory to another in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

hope you can help me, I'm looking for a command to let me copy all files above 500kB in my directory one to directory 2..

Basically I have a lot of Images in directory1 and would like to copy all images larger than 500kB to my other folder directory2..

Comment: Do you want to copy, move, or make a link?  You probably want to either move or make a (hard) link.  Copying is rarely necessary.

Comment: Well, I want to copy, because thats what i want. My folder of images is made by foremost, so I want to keep the collection as a whole untill later...

Comment: I notice that I am getting some votes down, why is this? Should i have elaborated that I had tried various things with xargs, which did'nt work before asking my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find` thus:

```
find directory1 -type f -size +500k -exec cp -nv {} directory2/ \;
```

- `-v` : verbose copy (you see what's copying)
- `-n` : noclobber (might not be available to your `cp` version): do not overwrite an existing file (just in case).

Comment: Thanks man, it really helped, I had like a million images ranging from 1kB to 7mB, and 99% of those where >500kB... 
They where collected by foremost because i acidently deleted an image folder...

Comment: Why the Backslash semicolon in the end?

Comment: @Qw_freak because for bash, a semicolon is a separation character, so if not escaped, it would not be sent to `find`. But `find` needs to have a semicolon to know where the `-exec` option ends. We must hence escape it.

Comment: Use `cp  --parents` to preserve the directory structure.

Comment: Use --maxdepth 1 to prevent a recursive find. It will only perform the find specifically on the target directory and not subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
find directory1 -type f -size +500k -exec cp {} directory2 \;
```